# Adding a default constraint in Oracle while altering a column

Tags: oracle, alter-table, default-value

I'm new to Oracle. I need to port a SQL Server command to Oracle.

I want to alter a column to add a new constraint with a default value.

#### SQL Server command

```
ALTER TABLE <schema_name>.<table_name> 
ADD CONSTRAINT [<constraint_name>]
DEFAULT (1) FOR [<column_name>]
```

#### Oracle command

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name>
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> 
DEFAULT (1) FOR <column_name>
```

I get the following error when running the Oracle query:

> ```
> Error report - 
> SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> ```

It might be because `FOR` is an invalid identifier?

But then how do I add a constraint with a default value for a specific column?

Do we need to alter a column and set the default value?

Which is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A default value is not a constraint in Oracle. You simply alter the column as:

```
SQL> create table tab1 (col1 number, col2 number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table tab1 modify (col2 default 1);

Table altered.

SQL> select * from user_constraints;

no rows selected

SQL> insert into tab1 (col1) values (0);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from tab1;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         0          1
```

Comment: I was also able to do this: `MODIFY quantity DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL`, it’s pretty flexible.